# How to identify the phishing email originates from a compromised account or a compromised server?

Tags: server, phishing

We have a whale phishing case, in which the sender is from the insider (we're using Zimbra email service for some specific user groups). A cursory investigation indicated that this account had probably been compromised.

My concern here is that is there anyway for the hacker to take over this account through server? I assume no because the email was associated with the specific email account.

Look forward to receiving your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compromised accounts are typically used to escalate internally, e.g. to launch a new phishing attack from inside in order to bypass spam detection or abuse trust between users (they have access to the compromised account's past emails too).

In most deployments, internal forgery is trivial; you could send mail as your CEO to anybody in the company (or externally) and it'd pass all of the spoofing detection tests. That means you have to look at the `Received` headers to determine what host the message actually came from. (If SMTP-AUTH is enabled internally, you should have the authenticated username available somewhere in the headers, typically the `Received` header added by the local SMTP server.)

> is there anyway for the hacker to take over this account through server?

Didn't you already conclude that "this account had probably been compromised"? If so, it has already been taken over. **Change that user's password as soon as possible** and perform an audit of all of that user's logins and emails going at least 72 hours before you believe it was first compromised (unless you have a definitive compromise time, in which case use that).

Perhaps I'm not understanding your question. If you're asking if there was a server vulnerability that was exploited and that perhaps the account was compromised in that manner, you'd have to [search](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/search_cve_list.html) for [CVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures)s related to all of your relevant server software. If you regularly update your software to the latest patched versions, this is a lower risk, but you should still check.